# Unable to install Postal to VPS

Tags: email, github, server, vps, postal

I'm trying to install Postal to my VPS via command:

**curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atech/postal/master/script/install/ubuntu1604.sh | sh**

But face error mentioned below :

Err:8 https://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing Release
404  OK

E: The repository 'http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing Release' does not have                                                                                      a Release file.

**N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa                                                                                       bled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                       ils.**

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add the RabbitMQ repository as described in the [website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html).

This script will include the GPG keys and both the RabbitMQ repository and the Earlang repository.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

sudo apt-get install curl gnupg debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring apt-transport-https -y

## Team RabbitMQ's main signing key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver "hkps://keys.openpgp.org" --recv-keys "0x0A9AF2115F4687BD29803A206B73A36E6026DFCA"
## Launchpad PPA that provides modern Erlang releases
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver "keyserver.ubuntu.com" --recv-keys "F77F1EDA57EBB1CC"
## PackageCloud RabbitMQ repository
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver "keyserver.ubuntu.com" --recv-keys "F6609E60DC62814E"

## Add apt repositories maintained by Team RabbitMQ
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list <<EOF
## Provides modern Erlang/OTP releases
##
## "bionic" as distribution name should work for any reasonably recent Ubuntu or Debian release.
## See the release to distribution mapping table in RabbitMQ doc guides to learn more.
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/ubuntu bionic main

## Provides RabbitMQ
##
## "bionic" as distribution name should work for any reasonably recent Ubuntu or Debian release.
## See the release to distribution mapping table in RabbitMQ doc guides to learn more.
deb https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb-src https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu/ bionic main
EOF
```

After that, don't forget to remove the old and defective entry from the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or your apt update will fail.